# javascript:history.back() OR homepage

Tags: javascript

I would like to add a button that will take a user back a page OR if a user used direct url to get to that page (so, `.back()` would take them back to google for example) - a user will be redirected to my homepage.

Looks like `javascript:history:back()` or `history.go` accept step attributes only (how many pages we can go back) and that is it. Will I have to tap into `session` or is there a way to do it with `history` object?

Comment: you can use `document.referrer;` to check it is your domain or not [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp).

Answer (score 4):

You can check the [referrer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) url with `document.referrer`, to see what was the previous page where the user come from. It can be empty that means user come from direct link, or clicked the link from other app links skype etc...

In the example I used `https://stackoverflow.com` as an example, but you can make it more universal if you use with `location.origin` [more info](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_origin.asp)

As @Jonas W. Mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48465040/javascripthistory-back-or-homepage/48465172#comment83923721_48465172), be sure you check the full domain in the right position in the referrer, because of security reasons.

```js
function go() {
  if (document.referrer.indexOf("https://stackoverflow.com/") === 0) {
    history.back();
  } else {
    window.location.href = "https://stackoverflow.com";

  }
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', go);
```

```html
<button>back</button>
```

Comment: `http://fraud.com?stackoverflow.com` <- i would not use indexOf for that... And you might use `location.hostname`

Comment: true this is a basic example, btw: if the user is already on the fraud.com why they want to link him to the original site, and wait maybe the user press the back button?

Comment: before somebody ask i know `=== 0` part can be a simple `!` but I try to make the example easy to understand

Comment: Stackoverflow is often used as a copy+paste ressource. Now imagine someone finds your snippet, does not read through it and includes it somewhere. I admit the injection is not really bad and actually cant think of an attack scenario. But who knows, maybe someone will find it...